# Javascript file reference in debugger missing

Tags: javascript

I am not exactly certain what I did to cause this, but I have been able to, up until a couple of minutes ago,debug my javaScript file(referenced using a script tag in a .aspx page I am working with) using FireFox firebug tools. Suddenly, I am unable to view the file via the FireFox script tab list. I scroll the list of script files included in my page, but I do not see the particular Javascript file I expect to be on the list. I am however, able to confirm that the JavaScript file is loaded along with the page information, under the HTML tag in firefox.

```
**No Javascript on this page**

If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).
```

I experience similar problem when using chrome. When I pull up the entirely loaded file, I am able to confirm that my javaScript file is correctly referenced. But for some reason I am unable to verify the script is being run or debug it.

The rest of the web application works file. Problem is just with the one page.

**ONE SOLUTION**
I created a new aspx file. Copied over the code from the faulty page and ran it, and it worked fine on both Firefox and chrome.